# Post array as parameters for API call

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to send a tweet to the Buffer API using the [POST /updates/create](https://buffer.com/developers/api/updates#updatescreate) method. I get a 405 error as a response. I think the problem comes from the `profile_ids` parameter which should be an array. What is the correct syntax for this case ?

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json" 
params = dict()
params['access_token'] = myToken
params["profile_ids"] = myID
params['text']=  "This is a test"
r = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(r.status_code)
```

Please note that `myToken` and `myID` are variables I did not share for the post.

Comment: *"which should be an array"* - `params["profile_ids"] = [myID]`?

Comment: If I do that, I have a 400 error.

Comment: Are you sure the url should have `.json` in the end?

Comment: yes, I am sure.

Comment: `params` is for URL query string parameters, don't you want `data=`?